# How to download file using curl with username/password and cookies?

Tags: url, curl, https, tcsh

I am trying to download data from secure HTTP.  I need to pass cookies in order to get past the login and download the data.  I try:

> curl --u "username" --d "https://url.datasite.login" --cookie-jar
>   auth.cookies
>
> curl --cookie auth.cookies -O "https://url.datalocation.file"

However after running the first command I'm given:

> curl:  no URL specified!

I've tried rearranging the order, changing quotations, using <> for the username, setting the username and url as environmental variables, etc.  Neither seem to do the trick. Have also changed the shell from tcsh to bsh and have tried using "wget" instead which retrieves a 400 Error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my commands for using cookies for curl:

```sh
# testing to see before login
curl http://localhost:3000/me
# undefined

# login
curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt  \
  -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"username":"blahblahblah"}' \
  http://localhost:3000/login

# OR--
# curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt  \
#   -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/x-www-urlencoded' \
#   --data 'username=blahblahblah' \
#   http://localhost:3000/login

# verify that we are logged in
curl --cookie cookies.txt http://localhost:3000/me
# blahblahblah

# download the file, (usually curl http://thing/file > file)
curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt \
  http://localhost:3000/download
# helloworldfile
```

and the sample application i developed to test it with:

```js
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {}
}));

app.get('/login', (r, s) => s.send(`<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>`));

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  var { username } = req.body
  if (username && username.length && username.length > 5) {
    req.session.login = username;
    res.end();
  } else {
    res.end('bad login\n');
  }
});

app.get('/me', (r, s) => s.send(r.session.login + '\n'));

app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.login)
    return res.send('bad login\n');

  res.set({
    'Content-Description': 'File Transfer',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="data.txt"',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary',
    'Expires': '0',
    'Cache-Control': 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
    'Pragma': 'public',
    'Content-Length': '14'
  });

  res.end('helloworldfile');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I'm downloading a data file, do I have to change "Content-type"?  Also this is for http, does it differ being secured https?  Your code yielded:  Error: bad action